# Count the number of entries in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, counting, read.csv

I would like to **count and display the number of entries** *(not rows nor columns)* in a **pandas dataframe** `df`
is there any predefined function that do it? how could I display the number of my data file's entries ?!

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:/python_learning/pandas_test/my_data.csv')

df.info()

if(df.notnull):
    print("dataframe is not null")
    #print("the number of entries is: ... ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution, and it's exactly what I wanted to display.

```
print(len(df))
```